# Are the Zemstvo Statistics Digitized?

Tags: russia, russian-revolution, statistics

There were massive statistics collected during the late Russian Empire (1861-1917)-- the "Zemstvo Statistics." They are available on microform at Yale (http://www.library.yale.edu/slavic/microform/zemstvo.html). Have they been digitized? If not, is there some problem with the data which has made it difficult to digitize?

Thanks,
JR

Answer (score 3):

That microform collection appears to be [published by Brill](https://brill.com/view/title/16327). Their website says that the searchable CD-ROM index is available for free, and they also have [a 60-page guide in PDF format](https://brill.com/fileasset/downloads_products/32120_Guide.pdf) free for download. The collection itself is extremely expensive, which explains why only a handful of top research libraries in the US and Europe seem to have it in their collections.

I do not see any evidence (in English, I don't know Russian) to suggest that a digital version of the actual collection itself is in the works, but I don't find this very surprising. Digitizing such a huge collection of data would expensive, and the target audience would be small.